# Python CX_Oracle : oracle query with conditions including a list of values(IN)

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-oracle

I would like get a list of values from a DB table in python using cx_oracle. I am unable to write a query with two where conditions one of single value and another of a list.

I am able to achieve it when I filter it two strings separately or only filter it by a list of string. But could not achieve it together!!

```
    output_list=[]
    catlist = ','.join(":x%d" % i for i, _ in enumerate(category_list))        
    db_cursor = connection.cursor()
    db_cursor.execute("""
    SELECT LWEX_WORD_EXCLUDE
    FROM WCG_SRC_WORD_EXCLUDE
    WHERE LWEX_CATEGORY IN (%s) and LWIN_USER_UPDATED = :did""" % catlist, category_list, did =argUser)
    for word in db_cursor :
        output_list.append(word[0])
```

The current code throws an error. But if I have either of the conditions separately then it works fine. The python version that I am using is 3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix and match "bind by position" and "bind by name", which is what you are doing in the above code. My suggestion would be to do something like this instead:

```
output_list=[]
catlist = ','.join(":x%d" % i for i, _ in enumerate(category_list))
bindvals = category_list + [arguser]       
db_cursor = connection.cursor()
db_cursor.execute("""
SELECT LWEX_WORD_EXCLUDE
FROM WCG_SRC_WORD_EXCLUDE
WHERE LWEX_CATEGORY IN (%s) and LWIN_USER_UPDATED = :did""" % catlist, bindvals)
for word in db_cursor :
    output_list.append(word[0])
```

Comment: Be aware of the non-optimal effect on the optimizer, DB cursor reuse, and the statement cache if you build up a SQL string like this and execute variants many times.  If you have a small, fixed number of values in the IN clause you may want to use a fixed list of bind names, and bind in NULLs where a particular execution of the query doesn't require a value for some bind variable.  See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#sqlwherein for the general concept